# How to tune the hyper-parameters of an estimator in Orange Tool

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, orange

Hi I want to tune/search hyper-parameters of SVM in Orange tool. How can I do?

I want to apply Exhaustive Grid Search to SVM

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: There is no such widget. You can do it by hand. Right? :D

Comment: yes. but i wonder its capability.